# Condition on Entry Box in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can i insert a condition to check if input in entry box is integer

i tried the isdigit() method didn't work

```py
def appendvalues():
    if entry1 != isdigit():
        entrymsg1 = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter numerical values")
```

Comment: The problem is that `isdigit()` is a method and not a function to be called like dat. You can change that line to `if entry1.isdigit() == False:` and it should work. But the more precise way would be to use `isinstance()` or `try` and `except` like said by @EricRoy.

Comment: What is `entry1`? If it is an instance of `Entry`, then use `if not entry1.get().isdigit():`.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `isinstance(entry1, int)` would work, but you may have some issues if the input is a string, as it will stop the program with the exception `ValueError`.

So, my preferred way to handle this is using a try/except statement. Here you have an example:

```py
def appendvalues():
    try:
        entry1 = int(entry1)
    except ValueError:
        # Return an error to the screen
        entrymsg1 = tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter numerical values")
    else:
        # Use entry1 somewhere
```

Note that this case, entry1 can be anything, so the user can insert a string (like `"1"` or `"not a number"`)

Comment: Yes, I checked it on python docs before publishing the answer, and when i tried it it worked fine.

Comment: oh yes, my bad :(